# Why can't I get the pictures from the path

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to map the images path from an array. I get the path but cannot load it. Is there any way I can solve this problem? If yes please help me.

```
  import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
    import axios from './axios';
    const base_url= "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/";
    
    
    function Row({ title, fetchUrl }) {
        const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    
        useEffect(()=>{
            async function fetchData(){
                
                const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
                setMovies(request.data.results);
                return request;
            }
            fetchData();
        }, [fetchUrl]);
        
        console.log(movies)
        
    
        return (
            <div className="row">
            
                <h2>{title}</h2>
                <div className="row__posters">
                    {movies.map(movie=> (                   
                        <img src={'${base_url}${movie.poster_path}'} alt={movie.name}  key={movie.id}></img>                    
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    
    }
    
    export default Row
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be with how you are attempting to compute the source urls. Use backticks (`) when using string templates.

```
<div className="row__posters">
  {movies.map(movie=> (                   
    <img
      key={movie.id}
      src={`${base_url}${movie.poster_path}`} // <-- use backticks for templating
      alt={movie.name}
    />                    
  ))}
</div>
```